# What is causing the block of Swift code to compile much slower than others?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have recently started analyzing the compile time of my Swift project using Build Time Analyzer: https://github.com/RobertGummesson/BuildTimeAnalyzer-for-Xcode. I have noticed that this method in particular is very slow to compile:

```
func placeStatusSwitch() {
        let switchX = tableView.center.x - (statusSwitch.frame.width / 2)
        var switchY = tableView.contentInset.top - statusSwitch.frame.height + tableView.contentOffset.y

        if let refreshControl = refreshControl {
            let navigationBarHeight = navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 0
            let expectedTopInset = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height + navigationBarHeight + statusSwitch.frame.height + MyTheme.verticalMargin - 4

            if tableView.contentInset.top >= expectedTopInset || refreshControl.isRefreshing {
                switchY = switchY - refreshControl.frame.height
            }
        }

        statusSwitch.frame = CGRect(x: switchX, y: switchY, width: statusSwitch.frame.width, height: statusSwitch.frame.height)
    }
```

I tried changing the Nil Coalescing Operator using instead:

```
var navigationBarHeight: CGFloat = 0
            if let navBarHeight = navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height {
                navigationBarHeight = navBarHeight
            }
```

However the compile time is still slow. Any ideas what might be causing the slowdown?

Comment: for slower execution you must familier with gcd.. In this run the process you want slower in background. and manage it with current process during execution. It's all about thread management.

Comment: Scientific Wild-Ass Guess (SWAG): Could it be during type inference of the arithmetic expressions? Does it help if you give those explicit types?

Comment: @ColinBarrett you mean for `switchX` etc add in `CGFloat`?

Comment: @KexAri Yeah. Or if that doesn't work add in intermediate bindings. Total guess, like I said.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

1. Adding explicit type annotations instead of inferred types.
2. Break long math calculations into smaller ones.